# Show that $\left<\mathcal{M}\right>=V$ iff $v_i$ is a linear combination of the elements of $\mathcal{M}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm struggling with the following problem:

> Let $V$ be a finitely generated vector space over the field $F$.  Let
>   $\left( v_1, \ldots, v_n \right)$ be a basis of $V$. Let 
>   $\mathcal{M}$ be a family of vectors in $V$.
>
> Show that $\left<\mathcal{M}\right>=V$ if and only if, for
>   $i=1,\ldots,n$; $v_i$ is a linear combination of the elements of
>   $\mathcal{M}$.

***I have the following:***

$\Rightarrow$) Suppose $\left<\mathcal{M}\right>=V$ such that $m_i \in \mathcal{M}$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Which means that $\left<m_1,\ldots,m_n\right>=V$. Given that $\left( v_1, \ldots, v_n \right)$ is a basis of $V$, $\left< v_1, \ldots, v_n \right>=V=\left<m_1,\ldots,m_n\right>$. So  does this mean that $v_i$ is a linear combination of the elements of $\mathcal{M}$?

I think I might have some right idea for the above but it might not be sufficient.

$\Leftarrow$) If I assume that $v_i$ is a linear combination of the elements of $\mathcal{M}$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$, this would mean $\lambda_1 m_1+\ldots+\lambda_n m_n=\left( v_1, \ldots, v_n \right)$ for $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n \in F$. How should I continue to show that $\left<\mathcal{M}\right>=V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do note that it is not necessary for $M$ to have $n$ elements. It is only a generating set, so all you know is that it has at least $n$ elements.

Suppose $\langle M\rangle=V$. So, every element of $V$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $M$. Now, $(v_i)_1^n$ is a basis of $V$, so each $v_i$ must be an element of $V$, so each $v_i$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $M$.

Now, conversely, suppose that each $v_i$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $M$. So,

$$v_i=\sum_{m\in M}\lambda_mm~~~\textrm{for some scalars }\lambda_m$$

Now, since $(v_i)$ is a basis of $V$, every $v\in V$ can be written as a linear combination of the $v_i$'s, so,

$$v=\sum_i\alpha_i v_i=\sum_i\alpha_i\sum_{m\in M}\lambda_mm=\sum_i\sum_{m\in M}\alpha_i\lambda_m m$$

with the last equality showing that each $v\in V$ is a linear combination of the elements of $M$, so $\langle M\rangle=V$